# Why is the set of Positive Rational numbers with a denominator of 3 Well ordered?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Why is the set of Positive Rational numbers with a denominator of 3 Well ordered?
I'm not sure but would 0.00000..../3 be possible subset?
Are there circumstances which a set with Real Numbers or Rational numbers which are well ordered?Other than specific list of elements?

Comment: What are you asking?  $\frac {.0000\cdots}3$ would appear to just be the number $0$.  Is $0$ positive? I'd say it was not, so then $0$ would not be an element of your set.

Comment: Do you believe that the natural numbers are well ordered?  If so, then this is more or less the same situation...the numerators of your numbers are a subset of the natural numbers so they inherit a well-ordering from that.

Comment: The set of positive rational numbers with denominator $1$ is just $\Bbb N$, which is clearly well-ordered. So it's not so strange that the same goes for the ones with denominator $3$. One might or might not find it immediately obvious, but at the very least it shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: $0$ isn't positive (unless perhaps you are French...). The least positive rational with a denominator $3$ is $1/3$, Then come $2/3$, $4/3$, $5/3$, $7/3,\ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming the Axiom of Choice, any set can be well ordered.

A countable set, such as yours, can be well ordered without the axiom of choice.  Since it is countable, there is a bijection to the natural numbers.  So, define the order on your set by the order of the natural numbers to which they map.

However, note that this is not necessarily a natural or familiar ordering of the set.  The whole of the rational numbers can be well ordered for this reason but the order will not be the familiar, natural order of the rationals.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's an order-preserving bijection from this set to $\mathbf N$, defined by $\dfrac n3\longmapsto n$.